# Merging different separate lines of text and sorting them out by certain pattern

Tags: r

With all the confusions, this is the question:

```
data = readLines("file.txt")
```

```
# data reads
[1] "JESSICA [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]: When there is sun, there was darkness."
[2] " However, nobody knew it was happening."
[3] " SAM [Day 1, 9:01 A.M.]: I thought it was not true."
[4] " But it was."
[5] " I thought it was "present" but it wasn't."
```

What I am trying to do is:
(1) merge the text by name (JESSICA, SAM).

I can identify the names in the data

```
test = regexpr("^([A-Z]+ \\[)",data)
names = regmatches(data,test)
final.name = sub("\\[","",names)

[1] "JESSICA" "SAM"
```

I can identify the date and time in the data

```
test = regexpr("\\[(.*)\\]", data)
time = regmatches(data,test)

[1] "[Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]" "[Day 1, 9:01 A.M.]"
```

What I am having difficulty is merging different lines for each names. That is, instead of this:

```
[1] "JESSICA [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]: When there is sun, there was darkness."
[2] " However, nobody knew it was happening."
```

I want every line to be:

```
[1] "JESSICA [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]: When there is sun, there was darkness. However, nobody knew it was happening."
[2] " SAM [Day 1, 9:01 A.M.]: I thought it was not true. But it was. I thought it was "present" but it wasn't."
```

Comment: This is not very clear. For example, `"NAME"` shows up in entry 1, 2 and 4 of `data`. Why does entry 2 not get separated from 1? What are the rules for splitting `data` by `"NAME"`?

Comment: That would be impossible unless there is some logic to recognize a "name." Do they appear each N lines? Do you have a separate list of valid names?

Comment: @Valentino Yes. I can identify the names and can form a list.

Comment: @givemecoffee That doesn't address our questions and doesn't really help. *How* can you identify names? What are the rules?

Comment: I tried fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is similar to now deleted @Maurits' answer.  We can create groups based on occurrence of `final.name` and `summarise` the text by pasting them in one group. I have considered `data` to be 1 column dataframe since it is easy to handle dataframes than plain strings.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(grepl(paste0(final.name, collapse = "|"), statement))) %>%
  summarise(statement = paste0(statement, collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)


#statement                                                                                                 
#    <chr>                                                                                                     
#1 JESSICA [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]: When there is sun, there was darkness.  However, nobody knew it was happening.
#2 SAM [Day 1, 9:01 A.M.]: I thought it was not true.  But it was.  I thought it was present but it wasn't.
```

---

Using base R approach we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(statement~cumsum(grepl(paste0(final.name, collapse = "|"), statement)), 
                    data, paste0, collapse = " ")[2]
```

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(statement = c(
       "JESSICA [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]: When there is sun, there was darkness.",
       " However, nobody knew it was happening.",
       "SAM [Day 1, 9:01 A.M.]: I thought it was not true.",
       " But it was.",
       " I thought it was present but it wasn't."))

final.name <- c("JESSICA", "SAM")
```